# XSLT - Add two namespaces in one node

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

This is my `XML` using `XSLT`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <RequestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <RequestResult>
                <Message>Request inserted successfully.</Message>
                <Response>true</Response>
            </RequestResult>
        </RequestResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And I want to **add two namespaces** in the `RequestResult` node (The result I want):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <RequestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <RequestResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MockupTesting" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:Message>Request inserted successfully.</a:Message>
                <a:Response>true</a:Response>
            </RequestResult>
        </RequestResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I use this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <s:Body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </s:Body>
        </s:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="RequestResult |RequestResult //*">
        <xsl:element name="a:{name()}"
            namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MockupTesting">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I need to add to the `SolicitarPeticionResult` node (which already contains a namespace):

```
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Comment: There are many answers on SO about adding namespaces to XML using XSLT - try searching.

Comment: I edited, only one answer, how add two namespaces to a node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a namespace to an element X when (i) the name of X is not known statically, and (ii) the namespace is not actually used in the name of X or in the name of any of its attributes:

(a) In XSLT 2.0, use the `xsl:namespace` instruction

(b) In XSLT 1.0, use `xsl:copy-of` to copy the namespace from an element that already has this namespace. For example, create a separate document dummy.xml

```
<i:dummy xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

and then do

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('dummy.xml')/*/namespace::i"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RequestResult">
    <RequestResult xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MockupTesting" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </RequestResult>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="RequestResult/*">
    <xsl:element name="a:{name()}" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MockupTesting">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry but that code doesn't return the `XML` that I want.