# XSLT - Delete prefix namespace specific node XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces, prefix

This is my XML with SOAP header and body:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <RequestResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <a:RequestResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MockupTesting" 
            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:Message>Message text testing.</a:Message>
                <a:Response>false</a:Response>
            </a:RequestResult>
        </RequestResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I need to **delete only the prefix** from the `RequestResult` node.
From this

```
 <a:RequestResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MockupTesting" 
            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

To:

```
 <RequestResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MockupTesting" 
            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

This is the `XSLT` **config file** that I use with version 2:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <s:Body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </s:Body>
        </s:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="RequestResult |RequestResult//*">
        <xsl:element name="a:{name()}"
            namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Testing">
            <xsl:namespace name="a"
                select="'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MockupTesting'" />
            <xsl:namespace name="i"
                select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'" />
            <!-- <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*" /> -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What should I add or modify to remove that prefix on that node?

Comment: You can't "delete" a namespace prefix, and in the vast majority of cases you don't have to do anything like that. Can you explain why you think it's necessary in your case?

Comment: Because the WSDL that I consume, it requires @Tomalak

Comment: Sorry, that's not a satisfactory explanation. I asked "Why do you need it?" and you answered "Because I need it." I think you need to give a better reason than that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "delete a prefix" from a node. A prefix is part of the node's name. To remove a prefix, you must create a new node with another name and possibly - as in your example - in another namespace:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MockupTesting">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a:RequestResult">
    <xsl:element name="RequestResult" namespace="http://tempuri.org/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @gtx911 Please stop talking in riddles. The above transformation produces the **exact** result you have asked for. If you want something else, edit your question and clarify. The same thing applies to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40589393/3016153